# How should I record in the database that an item/product is visible by 'all' groups?

Tags: sql, database-design, user-permissions

A user can be in groups. And an item/product is assigned groups that can see the item. Users can see that item if they are in one of the assigned groups.

I want neither public (anonymous users in no groups) nor groupless users (logged in users not in any groups) to see the item. But I want the interface to allow assigning the item an 'all/any groups' attribute so that users that are in any group at all can see the item.

Where/How should I store this assignment?

p.s. I expect the technique to also be extended to other entities, for example I'd assign a file to a category, and groups are linked to categories. so when a file is marked as visible by the 'all/any category' then if the user (thru groups and group-categories) is linked to at least one category then the file is visible to them.

**Decision:**

It seemed the choice was whether to implement as a row in a entity-groups table or as fields in the entity table. The chosen answer used the former.

And either managing the group membership in a table or adding JOIN conditions. The chosen answer used the former, but I'm going to use the latter. I'm putting an indirection between the query and usage so if (when) performance is a problem I should be able to change to a managed table underneath (as suggested) without changing usage.

I've other special groups like 'admin', 'users', etc. which can also fit into the same concept (the basis simply being a list of groups) more easily than special and variable field handling for each entity.

thanks all.

Comment: It's property of an Item so add a bit/bool column `AnyGroup` to Item. Use that field in your queries to include the item in all groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by both Martin Smith and Mikael Eriksson, making this a property of the entity is a very tidy and straight forward approach.  Purely in terms of data representation, this has a very nice feel to it.

I would, however, also consider the queries that you are likely to make against the data.  For example, based on your description, you seem most likely to have queries that start with a single user, find the groups they are a member of, and then find the entities they are associated to.  Possibly something lke this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT -- If both user and entity relate to multiple groups, de-dupe them
  entity.*
FROM
  user
INNER JOIN
  user_link_group
    ON user.id = user_link_group.user_id
INNER JOIN
  group_link_entity
    ON group_link_entity.group_id = user_link_group.group_id
INNER JOIN
  entity
    ON entity.id = group_link_entity.entity_id
WHERE
  user.id = @user_id
```

If you were to use this format, and the idea of a property in the entity table, you would need something much less elegant, and I think the following UNION approach is possibly the most efficient...

```
<ORIGINAL QUERY>

UNION       -- Not UNION ALL, as the next query may duplicate results from above

SELECT
  entity.*
FROM
  entity
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_link_group WHERE user_id = @user_id)
  AND isVisibleToAllGroups != 0

-- NOTE: This also implies the need for an additional index on [isVisibleToAllGroups]
```

Rather than create the corner case in the "what entity can I see" query, it is instead an option to create the corner case in the maintenance of the link tables...

1. Create a GLOBAL group
2. If an enitity is visible to all groups, map them to the GLOBAL group
3. If a user is added to a group, ensure they are also linked to the GLOBAL group
4. If a user is removed from all groups, ensure they are also removed from the GLOBAL group

In this way, the original simple query works without modification.  This means that no UNION is needed, with it's overhead of sorting and de-duplication, and neither is the INDEX on isVisibleToAllGroups needed.  Instead, the overhead is moved to maintaining which groups a user is linked to; a one time overhead instead.

This assumes that the question "what entities can I see" is more common than changing groups.  It also adds a behaviour that is defined by the DATA and not by the SCHEMA, which necessitates good documentation and understanding.  As such, I do see this as a powerful type of optimisation, but I also see it as a trades-and-balances type of compromise that needs accounting for in the database design.

Comment: could the group maintenance in 3,4,5 be performed by adding to the JOIN condition between groups and entity to extend any user group to join the global entity and by handling dupes?

Comment: I think I know what you meant; `INNER JOIN group_link_entity ON group_link_entity.group_id = user_link_group.group_id OR group_link_entity.group_id = GLOBAL_GROUP_ID`.   It is indeed possible, but with a few direct implications: If a user is a member of 10 groups, isVisibleToAllGroups entities will relate to the user 10 times, increase de-dupe work-load.  Predicates such as `ON a.id = b.id OR b.id = 0` tend to significantly impact performance.  The behaviour is mixed between the data in the tables, and corner cases in the code - a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: yup, pretty much what i was thinking of :) didn't think a bigger predicate would affect performance unfairly but i'm prepared to take your word for it. and de-duping will cost. as for the logic/behaviour, yeh the special case is in the SQL and not as cleanly understandable from direct inspection of data (tho a join to a group named 'global' should give a hint, perhaps in the way that IsVisibleToAllGroups would) but either way understanding complete behaviour could only be done after reading the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put it in the `items` table as a `boolean`/`bit` column `IsVisibleToAllGroups`.

It does make queries to get all items for a user a bit less straightforward but the other alternative would be to expand out "all groups" so you add a permission row for each individual group but this can potentially lead to a huge expansion in the number of rows and you still have to keep this up-to-date if an additional group is added later and somehow distinguish between a permission that was granted explicitly to all (current and future) groups and one that just happened to be granted to all groups currently in existence.

**Edit** You don't mention the RDBMS you are using. One other approach you could take would be to have a hierarchy of groups.

```
GroupId     ParentGroupId Name
----------- ------------- ----------
0           NULL          Base Group
1           0             Group 1
2           0             Group 2
```

You could then assign your "all" permissions to `GroupId=0` and use (SQL Server approach below)

```
WITH GroupsForUser
     AS (SELECT G.GroupId,
                G.ParentGroupId
         FROM   UserGroups UG
                JOIN Groups G
                  ON G.GroupId = UG.GroupId
         WHERE  UserId = @UserId
         UNION ALL
         SELECT G.GroupId,
                G.ParentGroupId
         FROM   Groups G
                JOIN GroupsForUser GU
                  ON G.GroupId = GU.ParentGroupId)
SELECT IG.ItemId
FROM   GroupsForUser GU
       JOIN ItemGroups IG
         ON IG.GroupId = GU.GroupId
```

Comment: yup, expanding 'all groups' to a concrete list of groups to add them individually is a no-no. but at least as far interface goes, now i'd have to check if the entity has a 'IsVisibleToAllGroups' field to know whether to show a checkbox (or the like). which means more complicated interface rendering.

Comment: @poop-deck - If you need such functionality, would the interface not need updating to accomodate it no matter what?  For example, I have an alternative approach in my answer, which takes a different view (from the perspective of the queries you'd write), but even that would need a way for you to update whether the entity is visible to all groups or not.  (In short, how would you envisage avoiding such a change to the UI?)

Comment: using MySQL but probably can finagle anything.

Comment: the addition you made is interesting :) and like @Dems suggestion uses a 'global' group that i had been leaning towards. the thing about the extra group is that the interface can show the same groups list without change (aside perhaps from ordering the global group to the top, or if needed, upon selection of the global group, cancelling selection of all others)

Comment: @poop-deck - MySQL doesn't have support for recursive hierarchical queries. The advantage of the hierarchical approach is that you don't need to worry about adding the users to the global group explicitly (though you do need to ensure the parent group is set for new groups) but given the lack of support in MySQL you would need a self join rather than a recursive query and you wouldn't be able to deal with arbitrary hierarchy depths.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a boolean, which needs additional logic in every query, I'd add a column 'needs_group' which contains **the name** (or number) of the group that is required for the item. Whether a NULL field means 'nobody' or 'everybody' is only a (allow/deny) design-decision. Creating one 'public' group and putting everybody in it is also a design decision. YMMV

Comment: i'd need "additional logic" to handle this new column too no?

Comment: But not checking a flag **and** joining an extra table, only joining the extra table. That reduces the amount of clutter-logic in the queries.

Comment: ah, ok, that would be better yeh. does it mean that each item links to only one group?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. If you can live with "an item belongs to only one authorisation group", and "a user belongs to only one authorisation group", you're home. It gets tougher if your data needs a many-to-many relation. I don't know your data.

Comment: yeh, an item can be assigned groups. and user in groups too.

Answer (score 0):

This concept should get you going:

[image]

The user can see the product if:

- the corresponding row exists in USER_GROUP_PRODUCT
- or PRODUCT.PUBLIC is TRUE (and user is in at least one group, if I understand your question correctly).

There are 2 key points to consider about this model:

1. Liberal usage of **identifying** relationships - primary keys of parents are "migrated" within primary keys of children, which enables "merging" of GROUP_ID at the bottom USER_GROUP_PRODUCT. This is what allows the DBMS to enforce the constraint that both user and product have to belong to the **same** group to be mutually visible. Usage of *non-identifying* relationships and surrogate keys would prevent the DBMS from being able to enforce that directly (you'd have to write custom triggers).
2. Usage of PRODUCT.PUBLIC - you'll have to treat this field as "magic" in your client code. The alternative is to simply fill the USER_GROUP_PRODUCT with all the possible combinations, but this approach is fragile in case a new user is added - it would not automatically see the product unless you update the USER_GROUP_PRODUCT as well, but how would you know you need to update it unless you have a field such as PRODUCT.PUBLIC? So if you can't avoid PRODUCT.PUBLIC anyway, why not treat it specially and save some storage space in the database?

Comment: is the additional product field not simliar to that proposed by martin earlier, along with its special handling? and the `user_group_product` relation not essentially the final join in the query proposed by dems? not sure i'd have such a relation as a table, perhaps a view.

Comment: @poop-deck In your question, you said: *"Users **can** see that item if they are in one of the assigned groups."*. I understood that as if users are **able but not required** to see it. If you need that kind of granularity, then you need USER_GROUP_PRODUCT to be a real table, not a view. If you don't, then this can be a view. BTW, yes PRIVATE looks equivalent to what Martin proposed.

Comment: wow, "able but not required" would be pretty granular, but then again a user might choose items they wish to see regularly (as a subset of all those they are permitted to see). if so then it would seem a table is required. thx.